# Allow Horizontal Scroll for fullpage section

Tags: javascript, html, horizontal-scrolling, fullpage.js

Here is my code.

```
        <div class="pagecontent" id="fullpage" >

           

        <div class="fullscreensection section">

           
        </div>

        <div class="fullscreensection section">

         </div>
        <div class="fullscreensection section">

            
        </div>

     

      



        <div class="fullscreensection section">

            <div class="versepicture-center" style="background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)),url(/docs/thumbnails/Meditate-Morning-7.jpg);"></div>
            <p class="meditate-verse">But I will sing of your strength; I will sing aloud of your steadfast love in the morning. For you have been to me a fortress and a refuge in the day of <span class="nobreak">my distress. </span></p>
            <p class="meditate-ref">Psalm 59:16</p>
        </div>



    </div>
```

As you can see I'm using the full page here. I want the "section" div to scroll horizontally on mobile devices.
This is what I tried but it's not working.

1.
let options = {
verticalCentered: true,
// scrollHorizontally: true,
normalScrollElements: '.section',
}
new fullpage('#fullpage', options);

When I used this it stops working even vertically ( The main purpose to use fullpagejs ).

2.
fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(true, 'right');

Answer (score 0):

You can't turn vertical sections into horizontal ones out of the box when using fullPage.js.

However, what you can do instead is initialise fullPage.js with a different HTML markup each time. Not ideal tho!

Horizontal scroll is only possible on fullPage.js when using slides inside a single section. (section = vertical, slide = horizontal).

So for example, this markup has 1 section containing 3 horizontal slides:

```html
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the only way o allow horizontal scroll with the mouse wheel would be by using the [Scroll Horizontally extension](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scroll-horizontally.html).

This other structure would create 3 vertical sections.

```html
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">Section 1</div>
  <div class="section">Section 2</div>
  <div class="section">Section 3</div>
</div>
```

So, to do what you want you would basically have to:

1- Use a different markup for the phone (small screen device) than for desktop
2- initialize fullpage.js for the appropriate markup
3- In case of resizing up /down you might want to destroy and initialize the new one.

So, personally, I would avoid this situation and I would just use the default responsive modes to disable snap scroll on mobile devices.

Comment: Hi @Alvaro, Thank you for your answer but here is the problem. This is not what I want. 
1. On Desktop Device default is okay snap scroll vertically and no horizontal scrolling.
2. On mobile devices I want it behaves the same in terms of vertical scroll there should be no vertical scroll bar and have snap scroll feature but with that, we can also able to scroll horizontally in order to see the hidden content

Comment: You'll have to be much more clear regarding what you mean by hidden content and horizontal scroll. With your data is almost impossible to guess what you need. Create an isolated reproduction of it in jsfiddle or codepen to illustrate your issue.